# (Script) Is it possible to create a transaction that is spendable to only one address?

Tags: script

I'm reading up on Script, which is pretty advanced stuff for a web developer like myself. I'm wondering, is it possible to send a transaction that can only be spent to a particular address?

Example, "Alice sends 1 BTC to Bob. Bob cannot do anything with that BTC except send it back to Alice."

Is that possible and how would it be accomplished?

Comment: This is similar to this question:  http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/43959/restrict-the-bitcoin-usage-only-during-a-particular-period/  Perhaps that can give you an idea how to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: hey! may I ask what material you are reading?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify the subsequent script used when the current script is unlocked. The script that bitcoin is sent to has only two states, locked and unlocked. Locked means it doesn't move, unlocked means it moves whereever the one who unlocked it wants.

Comment: I was thinking it could be possible with P2SH, where the script being needed to unlock the funds would be one that sends the funds back to the sender.

Comment: A script that unlocks funds only unlocks funds. It cannot make any new transactions that are dependent on it do anything.